# Facebook Android SDK. Error validating access token

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to access user information from facebook sdk.But I keep getting this error.

```
{"error":{"message":"Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"error_subcode":460}}
```

Here is the call which returns me the error in the `response` parameter of the oncomplete function.

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;    //<-- error in response
            try {

                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                MainActivity.this.userid   = profile.getString("id");
                new GetUserProfilePic().execute();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + MainActivity.this.userid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("jsonexception",e.getMessage());
                facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(MainActivity.this, null);
                GetUserInfo();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
});
```

Sometimes I get the correct response also.I think this is due to the access token expiration if I am right.
So can you guys tell me how to extend the access token although I've used this `facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);` in the `onResume` method of the activity.

How to solve this?

Comment: As from experience its nothing relate to your code. There is limit in number of messages you can post per day via your app. So If you exceed that limit you will see this kind of error.

Comment: For this error, you would have to close the session (in v3b) or remove the access token (in v2), and have the user reauthenticate. This is necessary because they have changed their password, and any access tokens associated with the previous password will be invalid, and cannot be extended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the extendAccessTokenIfNeeded and extendAccessTokenIfNeeded methods require the native Facebook app to be installed locally.

(I don't know if you are using v2 or v3b of the SDK, but it's documented here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Facebook#extendAccessToken(Context,%20ServiceListener) )

The behavior you're seeing... is it in the emulator or a real device? If the former, you can install the native Facebook app as an APK from v3b of the SDK, available here: https://developers.facebook.com/android

Comment: I am using it on a real device.